# How To Set a FMX.Panel Color?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

FMX controls do not have a color property. What is the FMX equivalent to VCL.TColor?

FMX.Panel1.Color := clBlack

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted - it may be a common one for FMX newbies, but it's still a genuine question with clear-cut answers.

Answer (score 17):

Quoting [myself](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/how-to-have-a-blue-fmx-tpanel-redux/): in a nutshell, use a `TRectangle` instead of a `TPanel` (a panel's style is probably composed of a `TRectangle` anyway):

1. Add a `TRectangle` to the form.
2. Change `Stroke.Color` to `Gray`.
3. Change `Fill.Color` to whatever you want.
4. At runtime, change the colour with code like this:

```
MyRectangle.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blue;
```

Annoyingly, at designtime, a `TRectangle` is made to pretend it can’t parent other controls (in reality, any FMX control can parent any other). However, you can use the Structure pane top left of the IDE to reparent controls to it as you wish.

Comment: I am fighting to create a TRectangle at runtime, I have followed this steps, parent of a tlayout, in a styled form. The rectangle shows up correctly, everything works. But it is transparent (no fill color), whatever I make do not chage this. Any idea? (Delphi xe5up2)

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way :
-define the panel as needed
-put all necessary controls inside it
-add in it a Rectangle of the same size as the panel
-set its Fill Property to the colour you want
-send the rectangle to the back so other controls will be visible

This way, it looks like the panel has a Fill colour, but it functions as a panel, e.g. all controls within it can be made not visible at the same time, etc.